# Merge 2 data frames in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge, gps

I have 2 data frames: GPS coordinates

```
               Time             X             Y             Z
2013-06-01 00:00:00  13512.466575 -12220.845913  19279.970720
2013-06-01 00:00:00 -13529.778408 -14013.560399 -18060.112972
2013-06-01 00:00:00  25108.907276   8764.536182   1594.215305
2013-06-01 00:00:00  -8436.586675 -22468.562354 -11354.726511
2013-06-01 00:05:00  13559.288748 -11476.738832  19702.063737
2013-06-01 00:05:00 -13500.120049 -14702.564328 -17548.488127
2013-06-01 00:05:00  25128.357948   8883.802142    664.732379
2013-06-01 00:05:00  -8346.854582 -22878.993160 -10544.640975
```

and Glonass coordinates

```
               Time                    X                    Y                    Z
2013-06-01 00:00:00   0.248752905273E+05  -0.557450976562E+04  -0.726176757812E+03 
2013-06-01 00:15:00   0.148314306641E+05   0.510153710938E+04   0.201156157227E+05
2013-06-01 00:15:00   0.242346674805E+05  -0.562089208984E+04   0.561714257812E+04  
2013-06-01 00:15:00   0.195601284180E+05  -0.122148081055E+05  -0.108823476562E+05 
2013-06-01 00:15:00   0.336192968750E+04  -0.122589394531E+05  -0.220986958008E+05
```

and I need to merge them according to column Time - to get the coordinates of satellites from only the same time (I need all GPS coordinates and all Glonass coordinates from particular time), the result from above example should look like this:

```
                 Time         X_gps         Y_gps         Z_gps           X_glonass            Y_glonass            Z_glonass 
0 2013-06-01 00:00:00  13512.466575 -12220.845913  19279.970720  0.248752905273E+05  -0.557450976562E+04  -0.726176757812E+03   
1 2013-06-01 00:00:00 -13529.778408 -14013.560399 -18060.112972     
2 2013-06-01 00:00:00  25108.907276   8764.536182   1594.215305    
3 2013-06-01 00:00:00  -8436.586675 -22468.562354 -11354.726511
```

What I ended up doing is `coord = pd.merge(d_gps, d_glonass, on = 'Time', how = 'inner', suffixes = ('_gps','_glonass'))` but it copies glonass coordinates to fulfill empty spaces in data frame. What should I change to get the result I want?
I'm new to pandas so I really need your help.

Comment: Have you tried merging using `how=left`? And btw, shouldn't the `glonass` coordinates end up on all rows in the resulting `coord` df?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. It returns all gps coordinates and duplicated glonass coordinates

Comment: What's wrong with duplicated values, isn't this semantically correct?

Comment: In that example I have only one glonass coordinates in time 00:00:00 so I need only one in df

Comment: Could you please display what happens when you use `how=inner`? Because when you merge those two datasets the first row of Glonass should end up on all the rows of GPS where `time=2013-06-01 00:00:00`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You have 4 entries for '2013-06-01 00:00:00' in your GPS df and 1 in your glosnass df, if you merge these why would you not expect to see your glosnass values replicated for each of these time entries?

Comment: Yes Tingiskhan, that's exactly what happens. Is it possible to get only one coordinates, not the same in all the rows of GPS where time=2013-06-01 00:00:00?

Comment: Again I ask, why does this matter?

Comment: It's possible, sure, but why would you want to do this (as @EdChum points out)?

Comment: because I need to create an output file to look like I wrote

Comment: Do note that if you want the output file as the one you've specified, you'll have `NaN`'s on all rows except for the first. Which is pretty unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merging (I took the liberty of renaming the columns first), you can then iterate over the columns, test for `duplicated` and set these to `NaN`, you can't set to be blank as the column dtype is a float and setting to a blank string will raise invalid literal error:

```
In [272]:
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'X':'X_glonass', 'Y':'Y_glonass', 'Z':'Z_glonass'})
df = df.rename(columns={'X':'X_gps', 'Y':'Y_gps', 'Z':'Z_gps'})
merged = df.merge(df1, on='Time')

In [278]:
for col in merged.columns[1:]:
    merged.loc[merged[col].duplicated(),col] = np.NaN
merged

Out[278]:
        Time         X_gps         Y_gps         Z_gps     X_glonass  \
0 2013-06-01  13512.466575 -12220.845913  19279.970720  24875.290527   
1 2013-06-01 -13529.778408 -14013.560399 -18060.112972           NaN   
2 2013-06-01  25108.907276   8764.536182   1594.215305           NaN   
3 2013-06-01  -8436.586675 -22468.562354 -11354.726511           NaN   

     Y_glonass   Z_glonass  
0 -5574.509766 -726.176758  
1          NaN         NaN  
2          NaN         NaN  
3          NaN         NaN
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question @Patricia, but having `NaN` everywhere doesn't really make any sense

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense to not duplicate data that clearly should be